# WPDB Query Question with Category Only

Tags: wpdb

I am trying to pull up posts from only category ID 18 with this query for a plugin I am working on but it will not work. I can not use `query_posts` or `WP_Query` in the place I am using this.

```
global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID, post_title, post_content, post_date
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy
    ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    WHERE $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 18
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
    AND post_status = 'publish'
    AND post_type = 'post'      

    ORDER BY post_date DESC
    LIMIT 25" );
```

Comment: Why can't you use `WP_Query`?

Comment: Immediately scrolled down to comments to ask the same thing @chrisguitarguy.  I bet you can mr. x.

Comment: Also "it will not work" is not descriptive. What results do expect and what you get? Answering this will probably answer @chris question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a SQL problem. Your query is wrong. You forgot to include the term_relationships table in the query, yet reference it during the JOIN. By including the term_relationships table, that would solve the problem with the query.

```
SELECT ID, post_title, post_content, post_date
  FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS p
  JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS tr
  ON tr.object_id = p.id
  JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS tt
  ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
  WHERE tt.term_id = 18
  AND tt.taxonomy = 'category'
  AND post_status = 'publish'
  AND post_type = 'post'      
  ORDER BY post_date DESC
  LIMIT 25
```

Comment: "Your query is wrong", does not explain the issue nor the solution provided, please explain *what is wrong* and why the provided answer solves that problem.